# Why does Redux Promise Middleware not dispatch a rejected action for my example code?

Tags: redux, jasmine, redux-promise-middleware, redux-mock-store, fetch-mock

I use fetch-mock, redux-mock-store, promise-middleware to test the redux implementation of my application. I have following code:

```
import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import promiseMiddleware from 'redux-promise-middleware';
import fetchMock from 'fetch-mock';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import createLogger from 'redux-logger';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { ACTION_1, hostNameSearchActions }
    from '../../../src/actions/hostNameSearchActions';

const middlewares = [thunk, promiseMiddleware(), createLogger()];
let mockStore = configureMockStore(middlewares);
const SERVICE_URL = 'http://url_to_the_service';
describe('Testing thunk actions', () => {
let store = mockStore({ hostData: { key1 :'value'} });
const aHostNameSearch = bindActionCreators({ ...hostNameSearchActions }, store.dispatch).hostNameSearch;
afterEach(() => {
        fetchMock.reset();
        fetchMock.restore();
        mockStore = configureMockStore(middlewares);
        store = mockStore({ hostData: { key1 :'value'} });
    });
it('ACTION_1_PENDING, ACTION_1_REJECTED dispatched, payload matches expected payload', (done) => {
    fetchMock
        .mock(`${SERVICE_URL}`,
            404 );

    const expectedActions = [
        { type: `${ACTION_1}_PENDING` },
        { type: `${ACTION_1}_REJECTED`, payload: {error: 'test.body.error.message'}}
    ];
    aHostNameSearch().then(() => {
        expect(store.getActions()).toEqual(expectedActions);
        done();
    });

});
});
```

The problem is that 404 call I am mocking with retchMock always ends up being resolved as ACTION_1_FULFILLED. why would this be the case? Am I mocking the call incorrectly?

Comment: Can you show us your `hostNameSearchActions` and clean up the code in the question so that it's easier to read? The only reason the middleware would not dispatch a rejected action is if the error is not properly passed up your promise chain.

Answer (score 0):

Redux Promise Middleware always dispatches a rejected action when given a rejected action. If your mocked action always ends up being a fulfilled action, when you expect a rejected action, it is because the promise payload is fulfilled.

This can happen if you have any side-effects (e.g., any functions that use the `then` method on the promise) and don't properly pass the error up to the middleware. Without more context, though, it's impossible to give you a definitive answer. It would be helpful if you included your `hostNameSearchActions`.